# How to combine root route and children route in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Here I want that when user visit to `"/"` it should change to `"/todo"` but it is not working as expected

```
let router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "todo", // The root route
        index: true,
        element: (
          <>
            Here is the child element
          </>
        ),
        // Redirect to /todo
      },
      {
        path: "/board",
        element: <>Here is board</>,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

ayout.jsx

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Layout</div>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

This renders the `children` at `"/todo"` but I want to convert `"/"` to `"/todo"` without using any navigation.

but here it's working

```
{
        path: "/,
        element: (
            <RequireAuth>
                <Layout />
            </RequireAuth>
        ),
        children: [
            {
                path: "/project,
                element: <Projects />,
                children: [
                    { index: true, element: <ProjectTable /> },
                ],
            },
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this without *some* navigation action.

You can redirect from `"/"` to `"/todo"`:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true, // path is root "/"
        element: <Navigate to="/todo" replace />,
      },
      {
        path: "/todo",
        element: <Todo />,
      },
      {
        path: "/board",
        element: <Board />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Or if you really don't want any navigation action to occur you can just render the same component on both the root path `"/"` and on `"/todo"`:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true, // path is root "/"
        element: <Todo />,
      },
      {
        path: "/todo",
        element: <Todo />,
      },
      {
        path: "/board",
        element: <Board />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: Resse updated thwe quesrtion now plz check .

Comment: @nidhisharma I don't understand your post edit. What you are saying is working hasn't anything to do with the `"/"` or `"/todo"` routes.

Comment: @drewResse it's working means it changes the "/" to "/project" without adding any naviagation

Comment: @nidhisharma Sorry, I don't see anything in that last code snippet that would redirect from `"/"` to `"/project"`.

Comment: @DrewResse it's all right

Comment: @nidhisharma Would you like a running code demo, e.g a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), of the solution I propose?